# Is it impossible to select multiple booleans into variables using Informix?

Tags: sql, informix

I am facing a strange problem when selecting multiple boolean values into variables using Informix SPL.

It works fine to select a boolean value into one variable.
It also works fine to select multiple integer values into variables.

What does *not* work is listed below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
    DEFINE b1 BOOLEAN;
    DEFINE b2 BOOLEAN;
    DEFINE i1 INTEGER;
    DEFINE i2 INTEGER;

    SELECT FIRST 1 't' INTO b1 FROM systables; -- OK
    SELECT FIRST 1 'f' INTO b2 FROM systables; -- OK

    SELECT FIRST 1 1, 2 INTO i1, i2 FROM systables; -- OK
    SELECT FIRST 1 't', 't' INTO b1, b2 FROM systables; -- FAILS!

END PROCEDURE;

EXECUTE PROCEDURE test();
```

The error message is:

> SQL Error (-9635): An attempt has failed to convert an opaque type
> into another type without a cast function.

How can I avoid this error?

This appears on
IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC10WE; the
OS is Linux.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem in Informix 12.10.FC6 on a Mac and in Informix 14.10.FC1 on Linux.  It can be worked around by explicitly casting the second (or both) constants to BOOLEAN: `SELECT FIRST 1 't', 't'::BOOLEAN INTO b1, b2 FROM systables;` or `SELECT FIRST 1 't'::BOOLEAN, 't'::BOOLEAN INTO b1, b2 FROM systables;`.  I've yet to investigate whether it is only constants that cause the trouble.

Comment: This is a bug CQ idsdb00109936.  Thank you for a good reproduction.

Comment: Thank you @JonathanLeffler for your solution. It works nice.